# Open folder of saved images in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver for saving compressed images in a folder named Image Resizer now I want to open that saved images folder

Comment: Open the saved images folder in what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `image_picker` plugin in Flutter for opening the images from the device. It will provide an option to open the gallery through which you can open the folder of saved images.

You can get the image_picker plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

Answer (score 0):

below is the solution i did it

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
//import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';
import 'ext_storage.dart';
class SavedFiles extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SavedFilesState createState() => _SavedFilesState();
}

class _SavedFilesState extends State<SavedFiles> {
  List<dynamic> listImagePath = List<dynamic>();
  Future<String> _getPath() {
    return ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.PICTURES);
  }
  _fetchFiles(Directory dir) {
    List<dynamic> listImage = List<dynamic>();
    dir.list().forEach((element) {
      RegExp regExp =
      new RegExp("\.(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)", caseSensitive: false);
      // Only add in List if path is an image
      if (regExp.hasMatch('$element')) listImage.add(element);
      setState(() {
        listImagePath = listImage;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Saved Images'),backgroundColor: Colors.orange,),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _getPath(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
//                  print('data');
                  var dir = Directory(snapshot.data);
                  _fetchFiles(dir);
//                  return Text(snapshot.data);
                  return Container();
                } else {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
//          Expanded(child: Text('sss')),
          Expanded(
            flex: 19,
            child: GridView.count(
              primary: false,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              crossAxisSpacing: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 2,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: _getListImg(listImagePath),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
  List<Widget> _getListImg(List<dynamic> listImagePath) {
    List<Widget> listImages = List<Widget>();
    for (var imagePath in listImagePath) {
      listImages.add(
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Image.file(imagePath, fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      );
    }
    return listImages;
  }
}
```